# Bios doesn't recognize HD

Tags: hard-drive, bios

When I boot using a live CD, I can see all my partitions and files untouched. But when I enter BIOS, only my DVD-ROM appears in the boot options. I have an Asus notebook S46C. I tried to update the BIOS but to no avail. I tried all types of SATA modes (AHCI, IDE and AUTO). I'm really running out of ideas here. What should I do?

**EDIT** When I try to mount I run into this error:

```
user@debian:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt
mount: /dev/sda is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

**EDIT 2** Mounting sda1

```
user@debian:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
user@debian:~$ cd /mnt
user@debian:/mnt$ ls
null
```

All partitions are shown as null. But I can boot into a Debian Live USB and see all my files beautifully sitting where they should be.

Comment: Does the drive show in your BIOS? (note, I am not askig about BIOS boot options. These require a bootable partition in your MBR formatted HDD. But even without those it should see that a HDD it installed, even if it cannot boot from that).

Comment: Yes! In fact it does appear. In the section of Sata Controllers, where I can choose between AHCI and IDE. But they are all grayed out and I can`t do anything to them.

Comment: The output from your mount command is expected. You will need to mount a specific partition (/dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, ...) instead of the whole drive.

Comment: Also, you may need to use the "-t" option with mount to specify the correct filesystem type, for example "-t ext4" or "-t ntfs".